# How does SPListItem HasUniqueRoleAssignments property is calculated?

Tags: sharepoint-server, splistitem

Does the value for the property `HasUniqueRoleAssignments` of `SPListItem` can be found in the SharePoint DB or is it a calculated property?
And if it is calculated - then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be found by calling the `proc_SecGetSecurityInfo` stored procedure and getting the `IsScope` parameter from the result set.

`IsScope`:

> A flag indicating that the document is the securable object at the root of the scope.
>   [[MS-WSSFO3]: Windows SharePoint Services (WSS): File Operations Database Communications Version 3 Protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh624619(v=office.12).aspx)